# converting rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in sql server 2005  where there are 3 columns id ,question and answer.

the data is as below-

```
id  question  answer    
1   married    yes
1   name       John
2   married    No
2   name       Dave
3   married    yes
3   name       Rob
```

I'm expecting results like the one below-

```
ID  married  name
1   yes      John
2   no       Dave
3   yes      Rob
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Juan Carlos for editing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select ID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN question = 'married' THEN answer END) AS Married
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN question = 'name'    THEN answer END) AS Name
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID
```